# Reduce length of bootstrap pagination buttons

Tags: php, pagination

I'm using bootstrap in the whole document, I'm using it for the pagination too.

This link is awesome: [PHP & MySQL Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616697/php-mysql-pagination)
and it helped me a lot coding the method for pagination (I am using postgre, I changed a few things).

When I print each button for the pagination, I am using bootstrap's code:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_pagination.asp

```
<ul class=\"pagination pagination-sm\">$links</ul>
```

and:

```
$links .= ($i != $page ) ? "<li><a href='$explode[0]$final$i'>$i</a><li> " : "";
```

for concatenating new strings to the $links variable(of course first this then echoing $links).

Note: I am using explode() because I get my URL and I fix the the `&page=`

**My question is**:

How do I shorten the number of buttons to show per page?

At the moment my situation is the one in the screenshot. 
I'd love to get something like:

```
[current][2][3][4][5]...[61][62]
```

**EDIT**:

I changed the code to have the "current":

```
    if ($i != $page) { 
  $links.="<li><a href='$explode[0]$final$i'>$i</a><li>";
  } else {
    $links.="<li class=\"active\"><a href='#'>current</a><li>";
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

added new image thanks to 1st solution (it is now black because I changed theme in the meantime).

**EDIT**: adding the php code.

```
$perPage = addslashes(strip_tags(@$_GET["perPage"]));
$page = addslashes(strip_tags(@$_GET['page'])) ?: '1';
$startAt = $perPage * ($page - 1);

SWITCH ($direction){
case "SENT":
    $count = "SELECT count(*) as total, 'SENT' as direction FROM sent WHERE date >= '$fdate' AND date <= '$tdate' AND identification LIKE '%$identification%' ";
    $query = "SELECT *,'SENT' as direction FROM sent WHERE date >= '$fdate' AND date <= '$tdate' AND identification LIKE '%$identification%' "; 
break;
}

$res = pg_fetch_assoc(pg_query($conn, $count));
$total = ceil($res['total'] / $perPage);
if (empty($total1)) { $total1 = '0'; } else { $total1 = ceil($res['total1'] / $perPage); }
$totalPages = $total + $total1;

$links = "";
$absolute_url = full_url( $_SERVER );

for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
    $explode = explode("&page=", $absolute_url);
    $final="&page=";

    if ($i != $page) {
      $links.="<li><a href='$explode[0]$final$i'>$i</a><li>";
      } else {
        $links.="<li class=\"active\"><a href='#'>current</a><li>";
        }
    }

$query .= "order by date DESC OFFSET '$startAt' LIMIT '$perPage' ";
$result = pg_query($conn, $query);
```

**EDIT:
Found the problem in the jquery:**
it will not load, never, but when I call the function at the document=ready status, it will.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#paginateblock').css('margin-left','-110px');
    });
  </script>
```

I need this to work always, not only when the document is "ready", rather, at every click on 'paginateblock' or everytime I change page.

Anybody can help?

**SOLUTION #1:**
Thanks to the help of **S Gandhe** that provided me his code, I'm copying it here with my correction.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
    if($page >= 7){
        $start = $page -4;
    } else {
        $start = $i;
    }
    $end = ($start + 7 < $totalPages)?($start + 7):$totalPages;
    for ($start; $start <= $end ; $start++) {
        $explode = explode("&page=", $absolute_url);
        $final="&page=";
        $css_class = ($page == $start ) ? "class='active'" : "";
        $links .= "<li><a href='$explode[0]$final$start'>$start</a><li>";
    }
}
```

**CSS:** [the css for `<li>` did not change]

```
#page-selection{
    width:350px;
    height:36px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div id="page-selection"><?php echo "<ul class=\"pagination pagination-sm\">$links</ul>"; ?></div>
```

**SOLUTION #2 - FINAL:**
I modified the code a bit more, the pagination buttons are inside a `<div>` and the content is aligned.
Plus, Page #1 and #lastpage are always shown.

**CODE:**

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
  if($page >= 4){
    $start = $page -3;
  } else {
    $start = $i;
  }
  $end = ($start + 6 < $totalPages)?($start + 6):$totalPages;
  for ($start; $start <= $end ; $start++) {
    $explode = explode("&page=", $absolute_url);
    $final="&page=";
    $css_class = ($page == $start ) ? "class='active'" : "";
    $links .= "<li><a href='$explode[0]$final$start'>$start</a></li>";
  }
  $firstpage = "<li><a href='$explode[0]$final'1><<</a></li>";
  $lastpage = "<li><a href='$explode[0]$final$totalPages'>>></a></li>";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="page-selector"> 
    <div class="page-selector-field"><?php echo "<ul class=\"pagination pagination-sm\">$firstpage</ul>"; ?></div>
    <div id="page-selection" class="page-selector-field"><?php echo "<ul class=\"pagination pagination-sm\">$links</ul>"; ?></div>
    <div class="page-selector-field"><?php echo "<ul class=\"pagination pagination-sm\">$lastpage</ul>"; ?></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#page-selection{
    width:344px;
    height:36px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#page-selector{
    width: 450px;
    height:36px;
    overflow:hidden;
    /*margin: 0 auto; uncomment this if you want this bar centered */
}

.page-selector-field{
    width:50px;
    height:36px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left;
}

ul.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.pagination li {
    display: inline;
    width: 50px;
    }

ul.pagination li a {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what links you want to show? What if the current link is not the first? If you don't want to show all the links, then don't loop over all possible pages.

Comment: When I took the screenshot I was at page 54 (you will notice it is missing). Instead of this, I will change it to current, that is easy. I'd need help for the rest. I am not thinking a way to "not loop for all and only print 7 pages at a time", or "loop for all but only show X pages at a time" let's say

Comment: This is not a Bootstrap issue, you need to modify your PHP code to just output the number of pages you want. Please include the php code that generates the array with pages.

Comment: done, hope it helps! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

am not sure about the quality/performance of code, but you can do it multiple ways, 2 of them here. 
I actually started using lazy load and auto loading of pages when scroll rather page numbers, so I don't have the code.

1) JS/CSS:You can create a fix width div for page numbers and scroll to current page using current page number * each div width.
let's say your current page is 54 and each page number is taking 50px. you will set the margin left to -2000px something.

```
$('#paginateblock').css('margin-left','-110px');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/66wy0t19/3/

2) PHP : as you said you have the links in array. you can use array_splice to get just the 10 links based on current page number. so if it's 54. you will may be spice it from 50-60 for showing 10.

- now you will need 2 buttons. one to move the page numbers div and second to get to Next page (like 4th from 3rd).

**Update:**
Couldn't find the js code, but here is some code based on php solution.
one minor advantage is you won't print all 100 items on page rather just print 5 links.

```
echo "<ul class='pagination wrap'>";
if ($this->pageNumber - 1) {
echo "<li ><a href='{$this->url}/page_" . ($this->pageNumber - 1) . "/'  {$ajax_request}><<</a></li>";
}
$start =($this->pageNumber > 5)?$this->pageNumber -4:1;
$end = ($i + 5 < $this->total_pages)?($start+5):$this->total_pages;
for ($start; $start <= $end ; $start++) {
    echo "<li {$css_class}><a href='{$this->url}/page_{$i}/'  {$ajax_request}  >{$i}</a></li>";
}
if ($this->total_pages - $this->pageNumber > 1) {
echo "<li ><a href='{$this->url}/page_" . ($this->pageNumber + 1) . "/'  {$ajax_request}>>></a></li>";
}

echo "</ul>";[![the output looks like this. ofcourse with classes. but i use bootstrap too.][1]][1]
```

[image]

**Update 2:**
Assuming each page number is taking 50px. this should work.

```
var currentPage =27;
var paginateBlockMargin = (Math.ceil(currentPage/2) * 100)-100;
$('#paginateblock').css('margin-left', '-'+paginateBlockMargin+'px');



 Check t  https://jsfiddle.net/66wy0t19/14/
```

This is the PHP code using your variables. You would need to replace your for loop with following. Prefer PHP code, as you will still need a lot of consideration in above JS. I wish I could find that JS code I had. sad.

```
if($page > 5){
       $start =  $page -4;
    }
    $end = ($start + 5 < $totalPages)?($start + 5):$totalPages;
    for ($start; $start <= $end ; $start++) {
        $explode = explode("&page=", $absolute_url);
        $final="&page=";
        $css_class = ($page == $start ) ? "class='active'" : "";
        $links .= "<li><a href='$explode[0]$final$start'>$start</a><li>";
    }
```

Comment: Both the solutions seems great! First upvote for the great ideas! let me try and I'll tell you

Comment: Ok so, the #1 concept works. Now I have 5 buttons [1][2][3][4][current] but I can see there are others buttons behind this row. I'll attach a picture. Something with the CSS that must be correct, I'll see if I can do it myself.
When I'm on the 5th page (current), the bar does not "move". How would you scroll horizontally, that when I'm in the 5th page I can see some more buttons on the right ([6][7] ?

Comment: height: 35px; solved. even tho the bar is long, I only see 300px of width of 35 of height. I'm thinking that maybe the jquery code is not loading.. ?

Comment: 36px * not 35px. I'm having a look at the js

Comment: The php method looks hard to me to understand :/ may I ask you if we could continue with the jquery method? I am having it almost working, it shifts. But when the page loads with the new page number, the css -110px reverts, and it does not remain shifted.

Comment: Hi sorry the late, just saw it. I tried both of them. The php's got an error at line 250, your script starts at 180. line 250 is the closure of the current IF, and it is `} else {` for some reason, it does not like your IF.. (?) I do not know.. need to check better.  As for the JS, I'm sorry to tell you that it did not change. I'll try working on both today, in the meantime I wait for a correction or some miracle. Maybe I get to a solution [maybe]. The php solution is clear now to me, I guess I'll try this one first ;)

Comment: Ok I think I fixed, I tested a bit and it is what I want. I am updating the post with the current solution. If it works for the next minutes, my time need to test, I'll mark your answer as main ;) - good job mate!