# How to add Auto Increment in sql such that 1st ten inserts have id of 1 and then next ten with 2 so on

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a PHP Forum project. And now, I want to do pagination in my thread lists.

So, I want to know that is there a way to add auto-increment in SQL such that first ten inserts will have an Id of 1 and next ten will have an Id of 2 and so on...

Comment: Nope - you will have to code this yourself and BTW what do you mean by FIRST 10? Is that first 10 inserts?

Comment: yes. I mean inserts

Comment: @Rishabh Why do you want to cache the page number? Why not use a normal `LIMIT x,y` expression in your `SELECT` query?

Comment: I do not see the reason in CREATION of the column with such properties. Create common autoincremented field (`id`), and calculate the number which you need in the queries using according expression: `SELECT (id + 9) MOD 10 AS id, ...`

Comment: Your question is regarding "Your" approach to pagination. Do you think your approach to pagination would work if later I want to say delete 7th record? In that case, you would need to edit the page_number field all records from 7th to last.


Pagination is a read side problem. Solving it during insert is not a correct solution.
Please go through different Pagination strategies in this StackOverflow question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616697/php-mysql-pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto increments doesn't work that way. but if you really need to group your inserts with some id, you can use triggers. you can create an insert trigger and write your logic to set the field as per your requirement.